# Need to open .reg files some way (I think it can't be a text editor)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

My computer has some environment variables that I need to restore. The Registry Editor, unfortunately, does not have a way for me to VIEW .reg files. It can only import them, which I do not want to do because it will modify my whole registry. I absolutely cannot use a text editor because these files are huge. Is there some program out there which can view and explore extremely large .reg files?

Comment: They are just text files not sure what you looking for

Comment: how large are the reg files? Try opening it with wordpad built into W7.

Comment: So you basically want to import a `reg` file partially, filtering by key?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, a program that can view extremely large text files can do it. Some text editors can.  Editpad is one example one, google for others. Your title that you don't want a text editor does not follow from your sentence that " I absolutely cannot use a text editor because these files are huge." Your title is wrong and has a false assumption.

There may be text editors that only open parts of files. But that's not necessary.